# I want to update the image column only if user select the new picture using laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Store function for image

ProductController.php

```
public function store_image(Request $request, $id) {
    $image = Product::find($id);
    $imageupdate = $request->all();

    for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $n = 'photo_' . $i;
        if ($file = $request->file($n)) {
            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('img/products', $name);
            /*two parameter of move function are 1. name of directory and 
              2.name of the file to store*/
            $imageupdate['photo_' . $i] = $name;
        }
    }
}
```

Table for Product in SQL:

[image: Table for Product]

Comment: What is the actual requirement ? Your question is not explaining the requirement

Comment: @MayankPandeyz i have a form in which i only display my photo and if user wish to edit the photo he can add a new photo but the code which i have written replace all the field even if user only selects the photo for example user has 3 photo out of  5 field now  if the user wants to only change  1st photo to replace then to all the field gets replaced and the existing picture in column in field 2 and 3 gets overwritten in database with null